# Make NSTimer continue after closing and opening the game

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nstimer

I am making a clicker game and I need to have my NSTimers continue after closing the application. I looked this up first but I could not find a suitable answer for Swift. I think I can use UserDefaults but I am not sure how to apply it. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I know there is a lot of information on this.

```
var timerVar = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self,     
selector: Selector("selectorName"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func selectorName(){
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()
    Score+=1
    scoreLbl.text = "\(Score)"
}
```

Comment: You should specify what platform your application is for. It’s probably iOS, but you haven’t told us!

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you described what you are trying to achieve in terms of the gameplay, not the code. When and why does the score change?

Comment: The NSTimer works just fine and the score increases over time. That issue is the timer stops when the game closes. I need it to continue when I open the app and remember how many times the NSTimer was activated.

Comment: Duncan C has mentioned that I cannot pause and continue a NSTimer so maybe I am doing this all wrong.

Comment: I think I finally understand. So every time a button is tapped, a new timer is started that awards one point every four seconds. I think what you want to preserve is the timers themselves, although possibly the number of active timers is a good enough approximation. Do you want these timers to persist if the app is terminated and relaunched, or just resume after it has been suspended in the background (but not terminated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. However it is not pretty but effective i'll post the code maybe someone can clean it up or use a different method. I ended up making another variable called scoreIncrementor then made a NSTimer in the didMoveToView that ran every second doing a simple equasion of score = score + scoreincrementor. Here is the code should anyone need it feel free to edit to your hearts delight. For this I also made another label just to see what is being added "tempScoreLbl".

```
 var ScoreIncrementor = Double()
 var Score = Double()
 var scoreLbl: UILabel!
 var tempscoreLbl: UILabel!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (ScoreDefault.valueForKey("Score") != nil){
        Score = ScoreDefault.valueForKey("Score") as! Double
    }
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()

var ScoreIncrementorDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (ScoreIncrementorDefault.valueForKey("ScoreIncrementor") != nil){
         ScoreIncrementor = ScoreIncrementorDefault.valueForKey("ScoreIncrementor") as! Double
    }

    ScoreIncrementorDefault.setValue(ScoreIncrementor, forKey: "ScoreIncrementor")
    ScoreIncrementorDefault.synchronize()

    let scorePerSecond = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1 , target: self, selector: Selector("permanentIncrementor"),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

self.view?.addSubview(scoreLbl)
self.view?.addSubview(tempscoreLbl)
}


func permanentIncrementor(){
    Score = Score + ScoreIncrementor
    var ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreDefault.setValue(Score, forKey: "Score")
    ScoreDefault.synchronize()
    scoreLbl.text = "\(Score)"

}

func gloveUpgrade(){
    if Score >= 50{

        let scorePerSecond = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0 , target: self, selector: Selector("gloveUpgradeTimer"),userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        var ScoreIncrementorDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        ScoreIncrementorDefault.setValue(ScoreIncrementor, forKey: "ScoreIncrementor")
        ScoreIncrementorDefault.synchronize()
        Score-=50

        tempscoreLbl.text = "\(ScoreIncrementor)"

    }
}
func gloveUpgradeTimer(){
    //increase score per minute by .25
    var ScoreIncrementorDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ScoreIncrementorDefault.setValue(ScoreIncrementor, forKey: "ScoreIncrementor")
    ScoreIncrementorDefault.synchronize()

    ScoreIncrementor+=0.25
    tempscoreLbl.text = "\(ScoreIncrementor)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pause and continue a timer. You have to invalidate it and then create a new one. Record the time at the moment you start the timer, and then when you pause it, figure out the amount of elapsed time and use that to figure out how much time remains. Create a new timer with the amount of remaining time that you calculated.

Comment: Could I get an example I am still fairly new to swift.

Comment: Try to write it yourself. If you have trouble, post the code you've tried along with info about what problems you're having and I or somebody else will help you. You'll learn a lot more by working this out yourself.

Comment: I can do that but let me try and understand what you are saying. You want me to make another NSTimer that calculates the time while the app is inactive. But I don't want the timer to continue while the app is down. Just to start up when the scene is loaded again. And to have the amount of times I clicked the timer button to be in there. ie: 4 clicks = 1 point score per second.

Comment: No. You only want 1 timer.

Answer (score 0):

> This doesn’t address what the asked wanted, but maybe it will be useful for someone else.

iOS apps can not run arbitrarily in the background, as discussed in [*Background Execution* in Apple’s *App Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). It would be really inefficient use of the battery to wake your app up every 4 seconds to increment a counter; imagine if every app did this and there were hundreds installed. See [*Minimize Timer Use* in Apple’s *Energy Efficiency Guide for iOS Apps*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MinimizeTimerUse.html).

Instead, store the previous time you updated the score, then when your app is running again it can calculate the difference from now and update the score accordingly. I’d say calculating the score is a better design even when the app is in the foreground.

You can get the current time from the [`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent) function, or by using [`NSDate()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/date).

---

Code style: This isn’t relevant to the problem, but there are a few things I would do differently if I did decide to write that method:

```
func incrementScore() {
    score += 1
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setValue(score, forKey: "Score")
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
}
```

- Name the method something meaningful.
- Use `let` instead of `var` for the standard user defaults reference, since it does not change.
- It isn’t `ScoreDefaults`. This is the shared standard user defaults object, not specific to scores.
- It’s more common for variable and property names to begin with a lowercase letter.
- Synchronising user defaults is usually unnecessary.

Comment: Ok so that solves a problem I don't have. I am not trying to make the score calculate for the time the app is closed. When I activate the NSTimer say 4 times. It gives me 1 + score per second. When I close the APP and open it back up. The NSTimer is no longer active. I need the NSTimers or an equivalent score incrementation to be active on start up that is equal to the amount of score++ that was given by the NSTimer

Comment: Basically making the incrementation permanent. Except when the app is in the background.

Comment: You should put this info in your question. You probably want to listen for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and invalidate your timer, and listen for 
`UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and set up a new timer.

Comment: Why do you need to save the score while in the background? Maybe read [Execution States for Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)